# SQL query not bringing intended results

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I essentially need to pull out a leadership board if you like of memberID, their first names, last names and their result and order them into highest first.

So far I have the first names and surnames appearing and then results however my query seems to be incorrect as it's showing all possible names, with all possible results as seen below (I know I need a `join`, not sure how though and which one):

[image: Incorrect Results]

Below I have actually posted what the results look like within the table:

[image: What phpMyAdmin shows for results]

The info and tables needed below are:

- `tblMember` holds the `fldMemberID`, `fldFName`, `fldSName`
- `tblMembEntComp` holds the `fldResult`.

So far I have this, but it's not quite right as you can see on my first screenshot.

```
<div class="grid-2"> 
    <p><b>LEADERSHIP BOARD</b></p>
    <?php
        $query = "SELECT `tblMember`.`fldFName`, `tblMember`.`fldSName`, `tblMembEntComp`.`fldResult` FROM `tblMember`, `tblMembEntComp`";

        $result = $conn -> query($query);

        while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) 
            {
                echo $row['fldFName']." ".$row['fldSName']." ".$row['fldResult']."<br>";
            } 
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the columns that relate the two tables:

```
SELECT m.fldFName, m.fldSName, e.fldResult
FROM tblMember AS m
JOIN tblMembEntComp as e ON m.fldMemberID = e.fldMemberID
```

Otherwise you get a full cross product between the two tables.

Comment: Hi @Barmar can I just ask what the m and e are? Variables or table names?

Comment: They're aliases for the tables, so you don't have to write out the long table names everywhere.

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING!!!! Thank you @BarMar. Is this classed as in inner join?

Answer (score 1):

Use for example `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.*
FROM tblMember T1
LEFT JOIN tblMembEntComp T2
ON T1.UniqueCommonField = T2.UniqueCommonField;
```